# What commands to run when initializing a new project directory?

Tags: reactjs, git, npm

I'm creating a JS web app, and I know there are a lot of commands I use to set up my project: `git init`, `npm init`, etc. However, I also want to do two other things that sort of set up a barebones project for me: `create-react-app` and `truffle init`.

What exactly do each of these commands do, and what is the correct order I should run them in (truffle init I believe just creates some folders)?

I am mostly wondering if multiple package.json files are bad, or node_modules folders, or git files, since create-react-app seems to do some of things `git init` and `npm init` do. For one, I know create-react-app initiates a git repo. But I would like to put all react stuff in a "client" folder, and there are other things in the root of the directory. Is it bad to have nested git repos?

Comment: Read [the docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#quick-start). It explains the commands you need to setup a React App.

Comment: That just sets up create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: no, you shouldn't have multiple git files and node_modules folders and so on in your project (unless it's on purpose), simply because it makes it unclear which one your project should use.

`git init` creates a new git repository. You don't need to do this when using `create-react-app` and `truffle init`, because they already do it for you.

`create-react-app` creates a boilerplate for your project, and `truffle` is another boilerplate, so those shouldn't be used together. Pick one and stick with it.

When it comes to multiple git repos, there are different ways to do this depending on what you want. I suggest reading up on [submodules](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/GitSubmodules/article.html), which is the intended way to have repos inside other repos. An alternative is to use a [monorepo](https://semaphoreci.com/blog/what-is-monorepo), which means using a single repo for multiple parts of the project, for example client and backend.

Comment: When does one need to make a submodule? I'm thinking I only need one git repo in the root, but not in the client subfolder, which is what create-react-app will do. Also, do I need to run npm init?

Comment: The link I provided about submodules will answer your question. If you don't want a git project in the client subfolder, simply delete the directory named `.git` there (`rm -rf .git`), and you will remove that git repository. This will not affect the git repo in the root. No, you don't need to do `npm init` as it creates a project.json file, which you will already get if you use `create-react-app`.